# No underline in my download link

Tags: html, wordpress, download

My website is in Wordpress.  I have a download link in html.  See below.  On the site the link is not underlined.  My understanding is that it underlines by default.  What am I doing wrong?

```
href=http://mywebsite.com/mysetup.exe download>CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD A .EXE FILE</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be a few things. Your link needs an opening  tag, and quotes around the href are a good idea. It could also be that your site styles remove the underline from under a link. You can either add a CSS style for it or do it inline.

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/mysetup.exe" download style="text-decoration: underline;">CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD A .EXE FILE</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add one class in the hyperlink :

```
<a class="dlink" href="http://mywebsite.com/mysetup.exe">CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD A .EXE FILE</a>
```

Then add style in the css file

```
.dlink{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The miss tag was due to my not copying it off the website. 
 I tried this with no luck:     <a href="http://mywebsite.com/mysetup.exe" download style="text-decoration: underline;">CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD A .ZIP FILE</a>

Comment: I'm not familiar with CSS.  Is that something used by Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reply of "Ahmed Ginani", I would like to add that by default  tag will have underline. If this is not appearing in your case than there may be some some theme / plugin css which is removing your  tag's css...

So firstly try to find that conflicting css and if there is no way to stop it than use `text-decoration: underline !important;` to override existing CSS...

Let me know if you need further assistance...

Comment: Thank you, WildProgrammers.  Yes, that's what I thought, that it should show the underline by default.  So how do I check my CSS?  I am a newbie with Wordpress.

Comment: Do you know CSS and PHP Coding? If yes than just open firebug and find out conflicting CSS.

If you don't know CSS and PHP coding than you need to hire some dev...

Let me know if I can help you...